# Point to Polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create new polygon layers from postcodes latitude & longitude](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41985/create-new-polygon-layers-from-postcodes-latitude-longitude)

I'm running QGIS 1.8.0

I have a list of points that I need to convert to one polygon. So far I have been using the **Point2One** plugin which produces a zigzagged polygon, instead of one full polygon.

To change the output result, I modified the numerical order of the **ID** column in the dbf to connect points in order yet I still get the same result.

The "Create output features based on input field" or "Sort points by this field" yields an error

I've looked at
[Createing polygon layer from point data using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34992/create-a-polygon-layer-from-point-data) but my problem seems a bit different.

I thought converting these points to a csv or txt format might work.

This seems like fairly easy problem to solve but I'm hung up. Any suggestions?

Thanks all!

Comment: Is there an order to your points or do you want a convex hull? Maybe post a link to an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: Check this question I helped some earlier.  There does appear to be a problem(not sure) with convex hull in 1.8 that we adress  in the answer. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41985/create-new-polygon-layers-from-postcodes-latitude-longitude/42002#42002

Comment: There's an order to the points which I used to reorder in the ID column. The result would be a simple, closed polygon shape.

Comment: @RomaH, convex hulls works. Problem solved. Thanks all!